# Does Boost's gmp_int backend automatically optimize?

Tags: c++, boost, gmp

From my understanding of Boost's multi-precision wrappers, they will automatically take expressions like `c = a+b` and turn them into `mpz_add(c, a, b)`. Will Boost automatically perform optimizations such as turning multiplication by a power of 2 into left/right shifts, or other similar changes?

Comment: Boost performs some optimizations, but I don't think it replaces `*8` with `<<3`. `gmpxx` (the official wrapper that comes with GMP) does though, with gcc (and compatible) compilers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Interesting. Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.Multiprecision performs a number of advanced optimizations, mostly to minimize the number of temporary variables. For instance, it will reorder `a=(b*c)*a` to `a*=c; a*=b`. However, it does not (currently, Aug 2014) take advantage of gcc's `__builtin_constant_p` to optimize even further. `gmpxx` (the official wrapper distributed with GMP) on the other hand will replace `a=b*8` with `a=b<<3`. Note that without `__builtin_constant_p`, it would be a bad idea (in a generic wrapper) to test if the number is a power of 2 before multiplying: if it was worthwhile, `mpz_mul_ui` would already do it.

Also, last time I checked, other compilers (clang, intel, oracle) only had minimal support for `__builtin_constant_p` and couldn't take advantage of its use in `gmpxx`.